# Alert Dialog dismissing on ScreenLock

Tags: android

My Alert Dialog is dismissing when screen is locked and Unlocked.In my case,

1)Starting connection in asynctask (which is inner class),here progress dialog starts saying "please wait...".
2)After completion of connection ProgressDilog is dismissed and Alert Message is shown.

So,In this process when i lock the screen when Connection is started, Alert Message is not shown and the same Activity in previous state is shown.

```
alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
alertBuilder.setMessage(Constants.TEXT_REGISTERED_SUCCESSFULLY);
alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(Constants.TEXT_OK, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Util.saveData(Registration.this);
    Intent thanksYouIntent = new Intent(Registration.this,ThankYouActivity.class);
    Registration.this.finish();
} });
alertBuilder.create().show();
```

This is my Code for raising the dialog.I heard to bind the dialog to activity so  i tried like **alertBuilder.create().setOwnerActivity(RegistrationActivity.this)**.This is also not showing any results.

One thing I have no clarity is what happens to inner asyncTask which is running Connection when the parent activity is paused.Any body plz help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Sha.

Comment: Have you overridden onPause and onDestroy with some LogCat messages to see what is happening to your app when the screen is locked?

Comment: yes I already overrided them.I also overide the onsavedinstace method and saved bundle of current activity.When screen is locked and unlocked oncreate method is calling again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if am wrong.Form my observation when an activity is in paused state,the corresponding AsyncTask is stopped.
So,In my case when screen is locked connection which is in doInBackground of asynctask already starts execution.But due to the screen lock reasons asyncTask is stopped and onPostExecute is not Completing successfully.My alertDialog which is in onpostexecute is not displaying.So,I'm saving the response state of the connection and displaying it when oncreate is called on screen Unlock using a boolean check.

The below is the code.This is huge but couldn't cut more than that to explain my case.

```
   private static boolean alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly;
private static String _alertMessage; //alert Message is for saving the previous alert message displaying when screen is locked

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //coding part

  _registerImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//here the asynctask starts running on click
    private String _response;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _alertMessage = "";
        //post data for response
        String postcontent="Sucess";
        if(Constants.LOG)Log.d("Content to post is :", ""+postcontent);
        ResgiserAsyncTask asyncTask = new ResgiserAsyncTask(postcontent);
        asyncTask.execute(null);


   }
  if(alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly && savedInstanceState != null){ // check for Alert Message dismissed unexpectedly

    if(_alertMessage == null ? true : _alertMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("")){ //intialise the last state of alert message if no alert message is set

        _alertMessage = _Engine.get_returnMessage();//this is my engine where parsing is done,So i'll get the previous response of connection

    }

    if(_alertMessage != null){
        if(_alertMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TEXT_REGISTERED_SUCCESSFULLY) || _alertMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TEXT_SUCCESS)){//my success case

            raiseSuccessDialog();//this is internal method

        }else{//failure case

            raiseDialog(_alertMessage);//this is internal method

        }
    }

  }else{

    alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly = false;
    _alertMessage = "";
  }
}

private class ResgiserAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
    private String _postContent;
    private Document _document;
    public ResgiserAsyncTask(String postContent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly = true;//set the coolean to true and make it false Clicklistener of alertDialog
        _postContent= postContent;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        _document = Util.postPage(Constants.URL_REGISTRATION, _postContent, true);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(_document != null){

            String _response = _Engine.parseRegistration(_document);
            if(!Constants.TEXT_SUCCESS.equalsIgnoreCase(_response)){
                raiseDialog(_response);
            }else{

                raiseSuccessDialog();
            }

        }
    }

}

private void raiseSuccessDialog(){

        _alertMessage = Constants.TEXT_REGISTERED_SUCCESSFULLY;
        alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
        alertBuilder.setMessage(Constants.TEXT_REGISTERED_SUCCESSFULLY);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(Constants.TEXT_OK, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly = false;
                Intent thanksYouIntent = new Intent(Registration.this,ThankYouActivity.class);
                startActivity(thanksYouIntent);
            }
        });
        alertBuilder.create().show();

}

private void raiseDialog(String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    _alertMessage  = message; // intialise the message to the raised dialog so that when screen is locked the alert can be displayed once again
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new Builder(Registration.this);
        alertBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(Constants.TEXT_OK, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alertDialogDismissedUnExpectedly = false;
            }
        });
        alertBuilder.create().show();

}
```

Hope it helps for those who faced the same problem.Any better ideas invited.

Comment: **Updated**: A single Configuration in Manifest Fixed the issue

     
      android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Answer (score 0):

Override [`onCreateDialog()`](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog) for showing dialogs. It can helps.

Comment: Thanks for response.In on create method we willcreate the dialog and return it.My Doubt is how an android activity can bind a dialog to it if we just return a dialog from 'onCreateDialog()'?I implemented this thing.But not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

@sha
 there are some events raised during screen off and on you need to control that too.... the link http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ shoes some examples regarding this

Comment: Thanks for your response.Thats a good article.I solved my prob  by using some booleans and checking whether internet connection is completed.